# Pydot error: file format "png" not recognized

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, graph-visualization, pydot

I need to build a pythonic graph solution through pydot and when tried to run a simple code like:

```
import pydot

graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='graph')
i=1
edge = pydot.Edge("A", "B%d" % i)
graph.add_edge(edge)
graph.write_png('graph.png')
```

Which is designed to build a simple graph (A-B1) on the png file.
After fixing a lot of misconfigurations, now I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zallaricardo/Documents/Python/test_png.py", line 7, in <module>
    graph.write_png('graph.png')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydot.py", line 1809, in <lambda>
    lambda path, f=frmt, prog=self.prog : self.write(path, format=f, prog=prog))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydot.py", line 1911, in write
    dot_fd.write(self.create(prog, format))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydot.py", line 2023, in create
    status, stderr_output) )
pydot.InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 1. stderr follows: Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of:

logout
```

And till now could not find a straight solution to my particular environment. 
Any hint about how can I fix it?
Need to work for python 2.7 and mac os x 10.9.

My current installed packages:

```
cycler==0.9.0
decorator==4.0.4
graphviz==0.4.7
matplotlib==1.5.0
networkx==1.10
numpy==1.10.1
pydot2==1.0.33
pyparsing==1.5.7
PyPDF2==1.25.1
python-dateutil==2.4.2
pytz==2015.7
six==1.10.0
wheel==0.26.0
```

I just would like to reach the same result shown in https://pythonhaven.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/generating_graphs_with_pydot/

Comment: Try dumping the dot file with `write_raw`, and running the command manually, i.e. `dot -Tjpeg -o/output/file -v /your/dot/file`. What is the output of that command?

Comment: @memoselyk I'm not sure what you mean by dumping the dot file with `write_raw` but the output for the `dot -Tjpeg - ...` is:
`dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
Format: "jpeg" not recognized. Use one of: `

Comment: Is the `Use one of:` list empty? What about `dot -Tjpg:`? How did you install _graphviz_, from a dpkg or compiled it (with Homebrew/Macports)? Maybe your are hitting this [bug](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-jpeg-and-mavericks), please try graphviz 2.39.

Comment: For `dot -Tjpg:` the output is `Format: "jpg:" not recognized. Use one of:`. All the lists `Use one of: ` mentioned are empty. I used `pip install graphviz` through terminal, and after installing graphviz 2.39, running finally rendered the png file. Thanks @memoselyk!

Now the output for `dot -Tjpeg -` commands are full of graphviz stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try uninstalling `pydot2` and install [`pydot`](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot)?

```
$ pip uninstall pydot2
$ pip install pydot>=1.2.3
```

Without any change in the script, I got the following output

[image: Graph]